# Ускорение потоков

Tags: многопоточность, java, swing

С каждым запуском потока его выполнение все больше ускоряется (конкретно - FirstCircleRepaintThread, SecoundCircleRepaintThread, LineRepaintThread). Что надо изменить чтобы потоки не ускорялись "самовольно"? [Код на GitHub](https://github.com/rberla/rest5min), [JAR на Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kam6cmd6tkxnv9h/Rest5MinsV0.32.jar)
(Чтобы закрыть программу - быстро покрутите колесико вниз)

[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) Извините, но как "Проблема не актуальна" ?
Не актуальна для кого?!

Все, проблема решена на StackOverflow за 20 минут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глянул в код. Разве можно вызывать repaint() из постороннего потока?

Comment: А я то думал) И ошибки нет, и результата нет)